# How to verify that user input number is in fact a valid unsigned int in c

Tags: c

I am writing a program in c that takes in an argument from a user on the command line but that argument has to be a valid unsigned int. For example if the user put in the value -1, then I would have to print an error code. Or if the user entered anything higher than 4294967295, then I would also print an error code.

I am unsure how to check if their input is within the correct range (0 and 4294967295).

Comment: you mean num > 0 && num < 4294967295?

Comment: Use `strtoul()` to convert the string, carefully, and then check that the result was a valid `unsigned long` (error check the return from `strtoul()` carefully), and then validate that the result is not larger than `UINT_MAX` from `<limits.h>`.  There isn't a standard `strtoui()` or `strtoi()` function (but it wouldn't be hard to create them using `strtoul()` or `strtol()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: exactly :)

Comment: Do you want to reject a number with leading blanks?  Trailing blanks?  A leading plus sign?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler `strtoul()` accepts  a minus sign "If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type)."  `unsigned long` does not overflow due to negation, just wraps around.  Do not recommend a simplistic usage of `strtoul()`.

Comment: @chux: I did _not_ suggest simplistic usage of `strtoul()` — I suggested _careful_ usage of it, which requires handling issues of signs, leading and trailing white space, non-numeric characters after trailing white space if trailing white space is allowed, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> to verify that user input number is in fact a valid unsigned int in c

`strtoul()` is the right function to use.  It poses some problems as it accepts `'-'`.  Let us assume leading whitespace is OK and check the front end of the string manually.

```
// 0: invalid, 1: valid
int unsigned_int_valid(const char *s) {

  while (isspace((unsigned char) *s) s++;
  // Fail on '-' as any negative number is out of range.
  if (*s == '-') return 0;  // Could add code to allow "-0"
  if (*s == '+') s++;
  if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *s) return 0;
  // Code knowns string begins with a digit

  errno = 0;     // Clear this global value as code tests it later.
  char *endptr;  // Pointer where parsing stopped.
  unsigned long ul = strtoul(s, &endptr, 0);

  // Usually this test is needed to see if _any_ conversion happened,
  // but code knowns the first character is a digit.
  #if 0
  if (s == endptr) return 0;
  #endif

  // Could march down the end of the string allowing trailing white-space
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr) endptr++;

  // Extra text after the digits?
  if (*endptr) return 0;

  // Overflow?  strtoul sets `errno = ERANGE` when "outside the range" of unsigned long
  if (errno) return 0;

  #if ULONG_MAX > UINT_MAX
  // Does 'ul` value exceeds `unsigned` range?
  if (ul > UINT_MAX) return 0;
  #endif

  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be implemented as follow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    long long num;
    char * pEnd;
    if(argc>=2)
    {
        num = strtoll(argv[1], &pEnd, 10);
        if(pEnd==argv[1]||*pEnd!='\0'||num<0||num>UINT_MAX)
        {
           // printf("Error\n");
           //Generate error message
        }
        else
        {
            // printf("Success\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Using [strtoll()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/) to convert string to integer. `strtoll()` can be use  to check whether input is number or not. Then check number is in range [0, 4294967295].

**EDIT**

As [Luis Colorado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3899431/luis-colorado)  comment

> let's suppose we have the same problem with unsigned long long integers. How do we solve the problem then?

To solve this problem this approach may work with string comparison.
This version generate error for `-0` and success for `0` and was not handled there as OP doesn't clarify this situation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void trimWhiteSpace(char *ch)
{
    int j=0, i=0;
    while(isspace((unsigned char)ch[i])) i++;
    while(isdigit(ch[i])) ch[j++]=ch[i++];
    ch[j]='\0';
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned long long num;
    char * pEnd;
    const int max_len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", ULONG_LONG_MAX);
    char max_num[max_len+1];
    snprintf(max_num, max_len+1, "%llu", ULONG_LONG_MAX);
    if(argc>=2)
    {
        trimWhiteSpace(argv[1]);
        int len = strlen(argv[1]);
        num = strtoll(argv[1], &pEnd, 10);
        if(len==0||*pEnd!='\0'||len>max_len||(len==max_len&&strcmp(argv[1], max_num)==1)||argv[1][0]=='-')
        {
            printf("Error\n");
            //Generate error message
        }
        else
        {
            //Success
            printf("Success: %llu\n", strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get if the user types `./yourprog ""` with an empty string for `argv[1]`?  Just a weird edge case...

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, My previous code return success with empty string, Now I FIx this problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have used `if (pEnd == argv[1])`, avoiding an unconditional call to `strlen()`.  But yes, you've fixed the problem.  Hmmm, except perhaps `-0`; it isn't clear in the question whether that's like `-1` or not.  This sort of thing is always surprisingly complex — to specify and code.  But you're firmly on the right track.  You might think about using `UINT_MAX` from `<limits.h>` instead of the 9-digit constant.

Comment: As `UINT_MAX` is not defined as `4294967295`, depending on OP's contradictory goals (unsigned int vs. 4294967295), `4294967295` could be used instead of `UINT_MAX`.  Yet if code uses `UINT_MAX`, `strtoll()` may not be wide enough.

Comment: So then, let's suppose we have the same problem with `unsigned long long ` integers.  How do we solve the problem then?  using `unsigned long long long`s?

Comment: Thanks@LuisColorado Answer edited and this approach should work this situation.

Comment: @chux Error corrected. this may work. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> to check if their input is within the correct range (0 and 4294967295)
> to verify that user input number is in fact a valid unsigned int in c

[Edit]

Since the original far below lacks pizzazz, how about 2 stage check using `strtol()` and `strtoul()` if needed?

Code avoids direct first use of `strtoul()` which fails to detect negative values.

```
// Return
// 0: OK.  Value saved in *u
// 1: Numeric text found, yet out of `unsigned` range.  0 or UINT_MAX saved in *u
// 2: Numeric text found, trailing junk detected.  Value saved in *u
// 3: No numeric text found. 0 saved in *u
int unsigned_check(const char *s, unsigned *u) {
  unsigned long uval;
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  // Try first to convert to long
  long val = strtol(s, &endptr, 0);
  if (val < 0) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    *u = 0;
    return 1; // Negative value
  }
  if (errno == ERANGE) {  // Too big for long
    errno = 0;
    // Try 2nd to convert to unsigned long
    uval = strtoul(s, &endptr, 0);
  } else {
    uval = (unsigned long) val;
  }
  if (errno == ERANGE || uval > UINT_MAX) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    *u = UINT_MAX;
    return 1;
  }
  *u = (unsigned) uval;
  if (endptr == s) {
    return 3; // No conversion
  }
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }
  if (*endptr) {
    return 2;  // Junk at the end
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

**Original**

`strtoul()` is the right function to use.  It poses some problems as it accepts `'-'`.  Let us assume leading whitespace is OK and check the front end of the string manually.

Given `strtoul()` nuances, code could simple roll its own check of a string for valid `unsigned`.

`(white-space)*(+-)[0-9](0-9)*(white-space)*`
This one passes `"-0"`.  Fails other negative numbers.
Fails out-of-range.
Allows leading and trailing spaces.
Allows end-less leading zeros: "000000000000000000000000000000001".

```
// 0: OK
// 1: overflow
// 2: invalid character sequence
int check_unsigned(const char *s) {
  // consume leading white space
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *s)) {
    s++;
  }

  // get sign
  int sign = *s;
  if (sign == '+' || sign == '-') s++;

  // convert
  unsigned sum = 0;
  const char *first_digit = s;
  while (isdigit((unsigned char) *s)) {
    unsigned sum_before = sum;
    sum = sum * 10 + *s - '0';
    if (sum < sum_before) {
      return 1;  // overflow
    }
    s++;
  }

  // Test for < 0
  if (sign == '-' && sum > 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  // Test for no digits
  if (s == first_digit) {
    return 2;  // no digits
  }

  // Test for trailing white space
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *s)) {
    s++;
  }
  if (*s != '\0') {
    return 2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try a combination of steps below

> Regex Match

```
/* Compile regular expression */
        reti = regcomp(&regex, "^[[:digit:]]", 0);
        if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); exit(1); }

/* Execute regular expression */
        reti = regexec(&regex, argv[1], 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }
        else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
                exit(1);
        }
```

> Followed by conversion to integer

```
strtoul()
```

> Followed by restrictions max or min

Comment: `strtoul` does already what your regex does, except that `strtoul` accepts a leading minus sign, for which you must check. And a regex just to check whather the string consists of digits is a bit too much, in my opinion.

Comment: Sledgehammer; meet walnut…

Comment: Walnut crushed to death :(

Answer (score 0):

The standard library function `strtoul` can be used for this purpose like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

char *numstr = argv[1], *endptr;
unsigned long result; /* where we save our number to */

/* skip leading whitespace */
while (isblank(*numstr))
    numstr++;

errno = 0;
result = strtoul(numstr, &endptr, 10);
if (numstr[0] == '\0' || endptr[0] != '\0') {
    /* this branch taken if input is not a number */
else if (errno == ERANGE || result > UINT_MAX || numstr[0] == '-') {
    /* this branch taken if number is out of range */
} else {
    /* this branch taken on successful conversion */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted your solution and then changed mind... You cannod compare `result > 42949967295` as every `unsigned` (32 bit) value is below that extreme.  Edit your answer to eliminate that test, and I'll upvote it again.

Comment: @LuisColorado on some platforms, an `unsigned long` goes higher than `42949967295`. For these platforms, I need to explicitly test for this boundary. On other platforms, I expect the compiler to optimize this test away. I should use the corresponding macro though.

Comment: `strtoul()` does not fail with negative numbers. `strtoul("-1", NULL, 0)` returns `4294967295`, (`ULONG_MAX`).  It is lenient on that pesky `'-'` sign.

Comment: @chux Gotcha! I need to check for that, too.

Comment: @chux Wait, but isn't `errno` set in this case?

Comment: `errno` is not set as the digits `"1"` fit in the range of `[0...ULONG_MAX]`.  Then "If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type)."  Negation with unsigned math is well defined: value just wraps.  Detail:  gcc returns `errno==0` and IMO, the spec is convoluted in its wording

Comment: BTW: Maybe `endptr[0] == '\0'` --> `endptr[0] != '\0'`?

Comment: @FUZxxl, the problem can be transported to any platform and the problem will be exactly the same, but with other limit number.... Simply, you cannot compare an `unsigned` to be over the type's upper limit because of the definition of upper limit, it cannot have values above it.

Comment: @LuisColorado Please observe that the type of `result` is `unsigned long`, not `unsigned int`, thus I need to make sure that the resulting number is in range for an `unsigned int`. If the conversion overflows an `unsigned long`, `errno` will have been set to `ERANGE` by `strtoul`, but if I need to manually check if the number fits into an `unsigned int` as well.

Comment: @chux Yeah, fixed, just like the issue with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed some difficult problem to solve with `unsigned` types, as you cannot test for range (as in `unsigned` there are no values above or below the extremes ---every number is between the extremes)

One approach could be to check for overflow as you parse, as overflows on input lead to numbers below the maximum possible value.  You can read numbers, char per char, and flag an error on overflow (when you detect that adding a digit doesn't produce a bigger number) like this:

```
const char *input_string = <<the input string goes here>>;
const char *s;
unsigned res = 0;
const unsigned base = 10; /* numbering base */

#if INCLUDE_SPACES_BEFORE_NUMBER
while (isspace(*s)) s++;  /* skip spaces. Optional */
#endif
for (s = input_string; *s; *s++) {
    const unsigned old_res = res;

    if (!isdigit(*s)) {
        /* flag_error(non_digits_in_string); */
        SIGNAL_SOME_INVALID_RESULT_TO_FLAG_NONDIGIT_AND_RETURN();
        /*NOTREACHED*/
    }
    res *= base;
    res += *s - '0'; /* digits are warranteed to be consecutive by std */
    if (res < old_res) {
        /* AN OVERFLOW HAS OCCURED */
        SIGNAL_SOME_INVALID_RESULT_TO_FLAG_OVERFLOW_AND_RETURN();
        /*NOTREACHED*/
    }
}
return res;
```

But this approach is non valid, as `unsigned` overflow is Undefined Behaviour, so we have to check it before letting it to happen.

The next approach could be to consider a regexp to match the string for valid unsignned range.  As you point in your question, your unsigneds range from `0` to `4294967295`, and that can be matched with the following regular expression:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,8}|[1-3][0-9]{9}|4[01][0-9]{8}|42[0-8][0-9]{7}|429[0-3][0-9]{6}|4294[0-8][0-9]{5}|42949[0-5][0-9]{4}|429496[0-6][0-9]{3}|4294967[0-1][0-9]{2}|42949672[0-8][0-9]|429496729[0-5])$
```

[See DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cY0aR4/1)

if it does not match, the number is invalid or not in the range you request.  I have included the complete regexp to show you the pattern on it, so you can easily adapt it to other ranges.  This way, you only accept the whole space of valid digit sequences (I have not included leading zeros, as they would mark the number as octal if you want to follow C syntax, but if you want them, just insert `0*` between the initial anchor `^` and the next pattern `(...`, and the same for spaces/tabs, if you want to allow them precede the number.

Comment: "`unsigned` overflow is Undefined Behavior" is not consistent with "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented ...  is reduced modulo ...." C11 §6.2.5 9.

Answer (score -2):

I think we can implement this thing in a simple way,

```
If((variable_name>0)&&(variable_name<4294967295))
   printf("entered number is a valid unsigned int one");
else
   printf("entered value is not valid");
```

The above code solves your requirement but I am not sure the time complexity in it because of huge number of comparisons that may happen in it.

Comment: For a command line input, what will be the data-type of the variable `variable_name`? Because, `argv` is defined as `char *argv[]`.

Comment: @joy-cs the data type should be "unsigned int" if we declare the variable name as char, and reading the intput as string there are two cases 1. It sloves our problem as we compare the first column of the input as + or - and print the result. 2. If we want to do any operations using the declared variable we need to change the string into int as we use integer.parseint() in java so declaring the variable as unsigned int is helpful in long run in my opinion.

Comment: In fact, you want `x >= 0 && x <= 4294967295`, but that's inherently true for 32-bit unsigned ints, so you need anoter approach, possibly a wider int.

Comment: But what to do, if the data get truncated to fit into the allocated memory? E.g. your input is an unsigned long and trying to assign it into a your unsigned int variable to compare it. Even there may be a chance of type casting error.

Comment: Here we are not assigning the value to any any other variable, we are just getting the value at the run time and comparing the taken value whether it is in between the limits are not.

Comment: You cannot compare `unsigned` against those extremum values, as **all** `unsigned`s are between both.  Probably, on a good compiler you'll get a warning, telling you that expression will always be `true`.