# Determining the range of an unsigned int

Tags: c

An assignment is requesting that I qualify input number to ensure that it is within range of an unsigned-int on my machine. How do I determine what that range is? it says that the input needs to be taken in at execution time and that no assumptions can be made about what was entered.

I tried using plugging in different ranges (2^7 , 2^15 , 2^31) but they all resulted in overflow.

Comment: Are you supposed to do it by reading the whole string and using `strtoul` or a related function? Or are you supposed to do it by reading the individual characters and interpreting them yourself? What did your class study recently?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`UINT_MAX` from `<limits.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).  Of course, for this to make any sense, you will need to have read your number into a type *larger* than `unsigned int` (or be parsing it from a string as you go).

Comment: A int can never be bigger than max int, since max int is the maximum value of int.

Comment: [`strtoul()` What is the correct return value for very "negative" strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60955490/2410359) may be useful.

Comment: Also see [How to verify that user input number is in fact a valid unsigned int in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32600232/2410359)?

Answer (score 2):

> To test if an string converts to a `unsigned`

Use `strtoul()` to convert to a `unsigned long`.  Yet since that function rolls over negative text to positive integers, use `strtol()` first.

```
bool valid_unsigned(const char *s, unsigned *uval) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  int base = 0; // Use 10 here if only decimal text acceptable.
  long lvalue = strtol(s, &endptr, base);
  if (s == endptr) {
    *uval = 0;
    return false;  // No conversion
  }
  if (lvalue < 0) {
    errno = ERANGE;  // Perhaps calling code would like to test this.
    *uval = 0;
    return false; // Negative
  }
  if ((unsigned long) lvalue <= UINT_MAX && errno == 0) {
    *uval = (unsigned) lvalue;
    return true; // Success
  }

  #if UINT_MAX > LONG_MAX
    // Still could be a value in the LONG_MAX...UINT_MAX range.
    errno = 0;
    unsigned long uvalue = strtoul(s, &endptr, base);
    if (uvalue <= UINT_MAX && errno == 0) {
      *uval = (unsigned) uvalue;
      return true;  // Success
    }
  #endif
  errno = ERANGE;
  *uval = UINT_MAX;
  return false;  // Too big.
}
```

To do: Test trailing text.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the function [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) for converting the string input to an integer, then you don't need to determine yourself whether the input is larger than [`ULONG_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits). The function `strtoul` will report this, by setting the value of `errno` accordingly. However, depending on the platform, an `unsigned long` may be able to represent more numbers than an `unsigned int`. Therefore, after the function `strtoul` reports that the input range is ok, you should additionally verify that the number is not larger than [`UINT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

Another problem with using the function `strtoul` is that it will accept negative numbers as valid. We must therefore check ourselves whether the first non-[whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) is a minus sign.

Here is an example program which uses a function `get_unsigned_int_from_user` which will continue prompting the user for input, until the input is valid and in the range of an `unsigned int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

unsigned int get_unsigned_int_from_user( const char *prompt )
{
    for (;;) //loop forever until user enters a valid number
    {
        char buffer[1024], *p, *q;
        unsigned long ul;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //get one line of input from input stream
        if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "unrecoverable error reading from input\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small)
        if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "line input was too long!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "unrecoverable error reading from input\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //make "p" point to first non-whitespace character
        for ( p = buffer; isspace( (unsigned char)*p ); p++ )
            ;

        //since the function "strtoul" accepts negative
        //input as valid input, which we don't want, we must
        //first check ourselves whether the input starts
        //with a minus sign
        if ( *p == '-' )
        {
            printf( "number must not be negative!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //attempt to convert string to number
        errno = 0;
        ul = strtoul( p, &q, 10 );
        if ( q == p )
        {
            printf( "error converting string to number\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that number is representable as an "unsigned int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE || ul > UINT_MAX )
        {
            printf( "number out of range error\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
        //so that input such as "6sdfh4q" gets rejected
        for ( ; *q != '\0'; q++ )
        {
            if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*q ) )
            {
                printf( "unexpected input encountered!\n" );

                //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                goto continue_outer_loop;
            }
        }

        return ul;

    continue_outer_loop:
        continue;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int num;

    num = get_unsigned_int_from_user( "Please enter a number: " );

    printf( "Input is valid, you entered: %u\n", num );
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter a number: -1  
number must not be negative!
Please enter a number: -5000000000
number must not be negative!
Please enter a number: 5000000000
number out of range error
Please enter a number: 4000000000
Input is valid, you entered: 4000000000
```

The program behaves this way because `UINT_MAX` has the value `4294967295` on most common platforms.

The function `get_unsigned_int_from_user` is a modified version of my function `get_int_from_user` from [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73915292/12149471). See that answer for further information on how that function works.

Comment: Technically, the program should not reject a sequence of 2000 zeroes...

Comment: Andreas Wenzel,  Try `errno = 0; printf("%lu\n", strtoul("-1", NULL, 10)); printf("%d\n", errno);`.  I get "18446744073709551615 0".  (pc gcc).

Comment: The value `-1` is reported as out of range because `ULONG_MAX > UINT_MAX` on your system, which is coincidental

Comment: @AndreasWenzel To be fair, it's not a matter of the *compiler* implementation but the *library* implementation...

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Concerning `strtol()` and `strtoul()`, this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9fUQ.png) helps visualize the situation.

Comment: Corner case:  How to handle `"-0"`?  The _value_ of zero is representable as an `unsigned` even though it beings with a `-` : a pesky corner case.

Comment: @chux: Well spotted! I don't think I will make the effort of attempting to fix this corner case. Using `strtol` before `strtoul` for the sole sake of detecting the sign (as you do in your answer) seems rather wasteful of CPU resources, but it probably is the simplest and most reliable solution.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Note that in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74416660/2410359) the call to `strtoul()` only conditionally occurs: values more than `LONG_MAX` else it is just the one call to `strtol()`.

Comment: @chux: Ah, yes, that is a good idea. That way, in most common cases, only one of the functions must be called.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each implementation of the C Standard made choices about the size of fundamental (here integer) types. So an `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits wide, but it is possible to be 32 or 64 bits wide. See: [Integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Integer_types) and [Data models](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Data_models).
2. For simplicity, we assume that an `int` is 32 bits. Then the value of `UINT_MAX` would be: `4294967295`. This token is 10 digits long. So your input is definitively out of range if it is longer than 10 digits (@chux-ReinstateMonica made a good point in the comments below, e.g. an input of "+000000000000000001" would be longer than 10 digits but still in the range of an `unsigned int`).
3. Even if your input has 10 digits, it still could be greater than `UINT_MAX`. Therefore, parse the string into an `unsigned long` (`strtoul`) and test if the value is less than or equal to `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am confused, help me out please, what do you mean?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh yes, you're right, didn't thought about that case, thanks.

Comment: As stated in the other two answers, using `strtoul` by itself has the issue that it accepts negative numbers as valid input, by converting them to a positive number.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel My apologies, it seems that today is not my day, i removed the reference to your answer.